# Disabling jQuery Contextmenu's items

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

First of all, thanks for all the helps on my previous questions. Well my question involves jQuery contextmenus. I have a context menu which is working perfectly showing all different options, however, I need to disable a few options (Lets say **Item B** in code below) and I am failing to do that. Here is how the code is,

I have an array called menuitems which holds all the elements of the contextmenu, e.g.,

```
function createMenuItems() {
    var menuitems = {};
    menuitems['Item A'] = {
        click: function() {
            // Some Code
        }
    };
    menuitems['Item B'] = {
        click: function() {
            // Some Code
        }
    };
    menuitems['Item C'] = {
        click: function() {
            // Some Code
        }
    };

    return menuitems;
}
```

This function is called in the following manner,

```
menuitems = createMenuItems();
```

Now the context menu is being created using the following command,

```
element.children("a").contextMenu("myMenu",menuitems,
    {
        disable_native_context_menu: true
    });
```

Any help will be highly appreciated, Thanks a lot and looking forward to your expert advices

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are using 
http://code.google.com/p/youpivot/source/browse/trunk/chromeextension/include/jquery.contextmenu.js?r=46

As far as I can judge from the source code, there is no support for "disabled". You can try though and add it yourself, e.g.:

```
menuitems['Item B'] = {
    click: function() {
        // Some Code
    },
    disabled: true
};
```

And then in the plugin file add this:

```
if (item_options.disabled)
    menuItem.attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

after line 39 in the source provided by the link (I assume your file might differ from that so you can just find the similar place).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have suddenly realized that the menuItem is a li so disabled will do nothing.

You need

if (item_options.disabled) {
    menuItem.addClass("menu-item-disabled");
} else {
    menuItem.appendTo(menu).bind('click', function(e) {
 item_options.click($(this).parent().data("invoker"));
 e.preventDefault();
    });
}
So you basically move the click binding under the condition that the item is not disabled, and for the disabled item you add a class .menu-item-disabled which you can make, say .menu-item-disabled {color: gray}